# Indian citizen applying for UK visa from US

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications, us-residents

My mother in law is an Indian citizen residing in US. Can she apply for a UK standard visa from US?

Comment: Your question has probably been downvoted because of your lack of research. It should be easy to find out the answer from official sources, such as the UK visa applications website. If it wasn't, at least mention the places you looked so that people who are trying to answer your question don't waste their time looking in the same places. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Applications for UK visas can be submitted in any location where the applicant is legally present and where there is a processing centre/consulate etc.

So, yes, she can. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa